# PHP Table Won't Update Mysql with AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am having trouble with updating my mysql table with the use of PHP and Ajax.

The problem is that when I press the delete button it only redirects to the homepage and doesn't do anything to the MYSQL data.

**HTML**

```
 <tbody>
   <?php 
     if($qry->prepare("SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `is_deleted` = 0")){
     $qry->execute();
     $result = $qry->get_result();
     if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_array()){ 
   ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?=  $row['menu_code'] ?></td>
        <td><?=  $row['menu_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?=  $row['menu_desc'] ?></td>
        <td><?=  $row['menu_type'] ?></td>
        <!--<td><?=  $row['menu_code'] ?></td>-->
        <td><?=  $row['menu_price'] ?></td>
        <!--<td><?=  $row['sizes'] ?></td>-->
        <td>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" value="View" >                   
          <form method="POST">                              
          <input type="submit" id="delMenu" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete" >  
          <input type='hidden' id="delID" value=" <?php echo $row['menu_id'];?>" name="iduse">
          </form>
        </td>
        </tr>                                   
   <?php
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
 </tbody>
```

**DeleteMenu.php**

```
<?php
  include '../../configurations/config.php';

  $qry = $con->stmt_init();

  $iduse=$_POST['iduse'];

  $sqlCode="UPDATE menus SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE menu_id = $iduse";

   if($qry->prepare($sqlCode)){

    $qry->execute();

    echo json_encode(array(
    "status" => 200,
    ));

} else {
    echo json_encode(array(
    "status" => 400
    ));
}
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).on('click', '#delMenu', function(){
   var id = $('#delID').value();
   var ask = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
$.ajax({
 url: base_url() + "../functions/DeleteMenu.php",
       method:"POST",
       data: {'menu_id' : id,
              'is_deleted' : '1'},
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success:function(result){
                if(result.status == 200){
                    alert('Successfully removed!');
                    $('#content_load').load('views/menus');
                } else {
                    alert('Has not removed!');
                }   
            },
            error:function(result){
                //alert('Fail');
                console.log(result);
            }
        }); 
});
```

I need to change the "is_deleted" column on my menus table to 1 everytime I press the "Delete" button so I can hide it. I think something is wrong with my php actions or my ajax code but I'm having a hard time pointing it out. Any explanation or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in DeleteMenu.php change $iduse=$_POST['iduse'];  as $iduse=$_POST['menu_id']; because you are passing as menu_id in ajax call

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to prevent form submission by adding this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#delMenu', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ... 
}
```

Next.. your ajax request structure is:

```
{
    'menu_id' : id,
    'is_deleted' : '1'
}
```

So in php use `menu_id` instead of `iduse`:

```
$iduse = $_POST['menu_id'];
```

You'll have to troubleshoot the rest of the code logic since it seems like there are multiple bugs and you might find more..

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You're using both forms and ajax to update values. Remove form tag and just use ajax. Try removing form tag as below

```
 <tbody>
   <?php 
     if($qry->prepare("SELECT * FROM `menus` WHERE `is_deleted` = 0")){
     $qry->execute();
     $result = $qry->get_result();
     if($result->num_rows > 0){
      while($row = $result->fetch_array()){ 
   ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?=  $row['menu_code'] ?></td>
        <td><?=  $row['menu_name'] ?></td>
        <td><?=  $row['menu_desc'] ?></td>
        <td><?=  $row['menu_type'] ?></td>
        <!--<td><?=  $row['menu_code'] ?></td>-->
        <td><?=  $row['menu_price'] ?></td>
        <!--<td><?=  $row['sizes'] ?></td>-->
        <td>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" value="View" >                                                 
          <input type="submit" id="delMenu" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete" >  
          <input type='hidden' id="delID" value="<?php echo $row['menu_id'];?>" name="iduse">
        </td>
        </tr>                                   
   <?php
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
 </tbody>
```

and in the Delmenu.php, use the attribute passed by ajax.

```
$iduse=$_POST['menu_id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

update your file DeleteMenu.php with this code

```
<?php
  include '../../configurations/config.php';

  $qry = $con->stmt_init();

  $iduse=$_POST['menu_id'];

  $sqlCode="UPDATE menus SET is_deleted = 1 WHERE menu_id = $iduse";

   if($qry->prepare($sqlCode)){

    $qry->execute();

    echo json_encode(array(
    "status" => 200,
    ));

} else {
    echo json_encode(array(
    "status" => 400
    ));
}
```

Because you are sending "menu_id" in post type variable and there is no post with name "iduse"

Here is the code which you are using to make ajax call using post method

```
method:"POST",
data: {'menu_id' : id,
        is_deleted' : '1'},
```

so you can use this data as $_POST['menu_id'] and $_POST['is_deleted'] in DeleteMenu.php.

And Remove redirection after form submission by using [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all always assign an `id` attribute to your form.

**2. AJAX FORM:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#delMenu', function(){
   var id = $('#delID').value();
   var ask = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');
$.ajax({
 url: base_url() + "../functions/DeleteMenu.php",
       method:"POST",
       data: "menu_id="+id + "&is_deleted="+"1",
        //dataType: 'json', /* NO NEED FOR THIS */
        //cache: false,      /* NO NEED FOR THIS */
        success:function(result){
           console.log(result);  /* check console and see whats the error*/
                if(result.status == 200){
                    alert('Successfully removed!');
                    $('#content_load').load('views/menus');
                } else {
                    alert('Has not removed!');
                }   
            },
            error:function(result){
                //alert('Fail');
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
        return false; /* added so that your form submits with ajax*/
});
```